# Multiple same name variables for get by ajax

Tags: javascript, python

For my api somehow, I need to put two same name variables for entry point.

It works on browser.

`api?lines=141&lines=142`

Then I want to do this by Ajax

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data:{
            lines : 141, 
            lines : 121,
        },
    )}
```

However it is doesn't work.

How can use the same name two variable at the same time???

or is it correct practice??

Comment: `lines: [141, 121]` the backend should use a DTO which contains a collection called `lines`.

Comment: You have both `line` and `lines`... are you sure about this?

Comment: Use a FormData object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your query directly using the url parameter:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url + '?lines=141&lines=142'
})
```